# Python Json Expecting Value

Tags: python

i am quit new at python and i am creating an API but getting this error :

```
print(Data.json())
...
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is my code:

```
   import classes as  cl
   import requests
   key = 'xxxxxxx'
   symbol = '^BVSP'
   url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol={}&apikey={}".format(symbol,key)
   #request = requests.get(url).json()
   #Time_Series_D = cl.Times_Series_D(**request)

   class AV_api_daily_ibov():
      def __init__(self,key):
          self.key = key
          self.url =  "https://www.alphavantage.co/"
          self.symbol = '^BVSP'
          self.function = 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY' 

      def request(self):
          return requests.request(method='GET',url = self.url,params = {'key':self.key,'symbol':self.symbol,'function':self.function})


  Data = AV_api_daily_ibov(key).request()
  print(Data.json())
```

What i am doing wrong??

Comment: Your request isn't returning JSON. Print `Data.text` to see what it actually contains.

Comment: Is this solved? If not, do update your output of `print(Data.json())` to the question. Since the error is on the first char, its likely that you are not getting a Json response.

Comment: Yeay it was not a json, it returned a documentation about the API, i really dont know why hahahah thanks guys